# What is the difference between function() and function(void)?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, c

I have heard that it is a good practice to write functions that do not receive anything as a parameter like this:

```
int func(void);
```

But I hear that the right way to express that is like this:

```
int func();
```

What is the difference between these two function declarations in both C and C++?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a thousand other questions on the site network, among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167390/what-does-an-empty-parameter-list-mean

Comment: @LarsViklund it is only a duplicate if there is a question on this site. I cannot find one, so regardless of what is on SO, this is not a duplicate. Probably worth keeping this question around as a signpost if nothing else.

Comment: Related question: **[Understanding the difference between f() and f(void) in C and C++ once and for all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13319492/439793)**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22138663#22138663) and decided to keep it around with some edits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/is-it-better-to-use-c-void-arguments-void-foovoid-or-not-void-foo | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416345/is-fvoid-deprecated-in-modern-c-and-c

Comment: It is actually a BAD practice in C++

Answer (score 35, accepted):

C and C++ are different in this respect.

[C 2011 Online Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 10 The special case of an unnamed parameter of type `void` as the only item in the list
> specifies that the function has no parameters.
> ...
> 14 An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty
> list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
> function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
> definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
> parameters is supplied.<sup>145)</sup>

In short, an empty parameter list in a function *declaration* indicates that the function takes an *unspecified* number of parameters, while an empty parameter list in a function *definition* indicates that the function takes *no* parameters.

```
T foo( void ); // declaration, foo takes no parameters
T bar();       // declaration, bar takes an *unspecified* number of parameters

T foo( void ) { ... } // definition, foo takes no parameters
T bar() { ... }       // definition, bar takes no parameters
```

As far as C is concerned, you should never use an empty identifier list in a function declaration *or* definition.  If a function is not meant to take any parameters, specify that by using `void` in the parameter list.

[Online C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> **8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]**
> ...
> 4 The *parameter-declaration-clause* determines the arguments that can be specified, and their processing, when
> the function is called. [ *Note:* the *parameter-declaration-clause* is used to convert the arguments specified
> on the function call; see 5.2.2. — *end note* ] If the *parameter-declaration-clause* is empty, the function takes
> no arguments. A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is
> equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type `cv void`.
> If the *parameter-declaration-clause* terminates with an ellipsis or a function parameter pack (14.5.3), the
> number of arguments shall be equal to or greater than the number of parameters that do not have a default
> argument and are not function parameter packs. Where syntactically correct and where “...” is not part of
> an *abstract-declarator*, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”. [*Example:* the declaration
>
> ```
>     int printf(const char*, ...);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with varying numbers and types of arguments.
>
> ```
>     printf("hello world");
>     printf("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
> ```
>
> However, the first argument must be of a type that can be converted to a `const char*` — *end example* ]
> [ *Note:* The standard header `<cstdarg>` contains a mechanism for accessing arguments passed using the
> ellipsis (see 5.2.2 and 18.10). — *end note* ]

In the case of C++, an empty parameter list in either a declaration or a definition indicates that the function takes no arguments, and is equivalent to using a parameter list of `void`.

Answer (score 45):

In C, a function with an empty parameter list `()` can take **anything** for its arguments. Literally anything. This is usually used to implement a function which can take [a variable number of arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html), though these days it's considered preferable to use the more explicit ellipsis syntax `(...)` for these functions.

In C, a function with the parameter list `(void)` explicitly takes **nothing** for its arguments. That means the compiler can actually tell you you've made a mistake if you try to pass something.

In C++, these function declarations are equivalent. A blank parameter list means "no parameters" the same as `void` does.

Comment: Re: "This is usually used to implement a function which can take a variable number of arguments": Are you sure about this? I don't think I've ever seen a program that used explicit parameter-lists for forward-declarations of non-variadic functions and `()` for those of variadic ones. Do you have an example of a program that uses this convention?

Comment: A C variadic function *must* be defined with the `...` syntax, and it must have at least one named parameter. Defining such a function with `()` causes undefined behavior -- and there's no way for the body of the function to use the macros defined in `<stdarg.h>` to read the parameter values. This has been the case since the 1989/1990 standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson: This question, and this answer, are talking about predeclarations, not function definitions.

Comment: @ruakh: A variadic function must be declared *and* defined using the `...` syntax to avoid undefined behavior.